# How to run GATT command in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I'm developing an Android application for read/write data for a BLE device. The specification of the device has mentioned one service UUID and two feature UUIDs. 
`Service UUID: 0xFFF0`
`TX UUID: 0xFFF6`, `RX UUID: 0xFFF7`

And bunch of command formats as follows.

For example, for Get time:

`Command format: 0x41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CRC`

When running a `serviceDiscovery()` there are some additional UUIDs are appeared. But there's no use of them.

Is there any special way to run commands like this in Android?

I'm quite new to Android development. So, can someone help me to overcome this situation?

Comment: running a command means writin the data to write characteristics

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks. should we use `0x41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` as a single string and convert it to `byte` and write? I'm little bit confuse about setting up the command with this handle `0x41`, message `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` and `CRC` here. can you provide a simple sample code for me? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you likely need to write those bytes: `0x41 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, not put this as string, and then get it's bytes.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes I put it as a byte like `byte[] messageBytes = new byte[]{0x41, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00};` and then WRITE is successful. But this command suppose to return DATE/TIME value in same format as above. How do we receive the return value?

Comment: By reading from read characteristics.

Comment: With the bluetooth there are no *commands*, you just *read* and *write* data.

Comment: Hi @Tharanga

Did you manage to solve it?